# How to find all currency related digits REGEX?

Tags: regex

For a string that has free text:

```
"The shares of the stock at the XKI Market fell by €89.99 today, which saw a drop of a 9€5 
from last monday. If they do not level up again to 100€ by the end of this week there might 
be serious consequences to the company"
```

How to find a regex pattern that will extract currency related numbers?

In this case: 89.99, 95, and 100?

So far, I've tried these patterns:

```
[0-9]*[€.]([0-9]*)
\[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.\[0-9]{3})*,\[0-9]\[0-9]
[0-9]+\€\.[0-9]+
```

But these don't seem to be producing exactly what is needed

Answer (score 1):

One option is to match all 3 variations and afterwards remove the euro sign from the match.

```
(?:\d+€\d*|€\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d+€\d*` Match 1+ digit and € followed by optional digits
  - `|` Or
  - `€\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match € followed by digits and an optional decimal part
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F2DzXy/1)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"(?:\d+€\d*|€\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"

test_str = ("\"The shares of the stock at the XKI Market fell by €89.99 today, which saw a drop of a 9€5 \n"
            "from last monday. If they do not level up again to 100€ by the end of this week there might \n"
            "be serious consequences to the company\"")

print([x.replace("€", "") for x in re.findall(regex, test_str)])
```

Output

```
['89.99', '95', '100']
```

A bit more precise pattern for the number with optional comma followed by 3 digits and 2 digit decimal part could be:

```
(?:\d+€\d*|€\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yZcmsK/1)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution would be `[.\d]*€[.\d]*`.

Answer (score 0):

This need further testing but I would simply grab everything around `€` which is not whitespace, that is:

```
import re
text = """The shares of the stock at the XKI Market fell by €89.99 today, which saw a drop of a 9€5 
from last monday. If they do not level up again to 100€ by the end of this week there might 
be serious consequences to the company"""
values = re.findall(r"\S*€\S*", text)
print(values)
```

Output:

```
['€89.99', '9€5', '100€']
```